# Converting time to unix timestamp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

I have the following time format

```
"2014-06-02T16:23:13+02:00"
```

I want to convert it to the unix timestamp (since 1/1/1970). For the above example, The command should return:

```
1401725705
```

Are there a linux command for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date -d"2014-06-02T16:23:13+02:00" +%s
```

should work if you have a newer GNU coreutil. I tested with v8.22 latest.

if you are on a elder coreutil box like 8.4. it won't work, you could try replace the `T` with space. use string `"2014-06-02 16:23:13+02:00"` in `date -d"2014-06-02 16:23:13+02:00" +%s`

this is tested on `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)` with `coreutil 8.4`

```
$>date -d"2014-06-02 16:23:13+02:00" +%s                                    
1401718993
```

Answer (score 2):

```
date -d"2014-06-02T16:23:13+02:00" +%s
```

Comment: it returns `date: invalid date '2014-06-02T16:23:13+02:00'`

Comment: @MOHAMED, what does `date --version` tell you?

Comment: I tried with 2 linux the first one: `date (GNU coreutils) 8.5
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
`
The second one is from BusyBox: `BusyBox v1.19.4`

Answer (score 0):

As pacholik indicates, `%s` is the way to convert date to seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

You can try either of these (note the usage of `-d` or `--date=`, as well as `%s` with `+` in or outside the quotes:

```
$ date --date="2014-06-02T16:23:13+02:00" "+%s"
1401718993

$ date --date="2014-06-02T16:23:13+02:00" +"%s"
1401718993

$ date -d"2014-06-02T16:23:13+02:00" +"%s"
1401718993
```

As a side note, you can do the opposite with `-d@TIME`:

```
$ date -d@1401718993
Mon Jun  2 14:23:13 UTC 2014
```

---

I see you were having problems with the `T` - [time designator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations):

```
$ date -d"$(sed 's/\(.*\)T\(.*\).*/\1 \2/' <<< "2014-06-02T16:23:13+02:00")" +"%s"
1401718993
```

This `sed` gets the string and removes the `T` in the middle.

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)T\(.*\).*/\1 \2/' <<< "2014-06-02T16:23:13+02:00"
2014-06-02 16:23:13+02:00
```